# Detect EF connection string, and turn it into simple ADO.NET connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is EF connection string:

```
metadata=res://*/ModEntity.csdl|res://*/ModEntity.ssdl|res://*/ModEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SomeServer;Initial Catalog=SomeCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Entity;Password=SomePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;
```

A simple ADO.NET connection string is:

```
Data Source=SomeServer;Initial Catalog=SomeCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Entity;Password=SomePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

I want to detect that a given connection string is in EF format or an ADO.NET one? And if so, I want to extract out the simple section.

I'm using `System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder` to build the connection string and extract the simple section, but it only works when a real EF connection string is given. Otherwise it throws exception.

How can I safely do that?

Comment: Well then you already have a way of detecting if it is an EF connection string and can get the value out of it.

Comment: What exception, and where?